# Find position knowing 2 points and distances to those points

Tags: general-topology, trigonometry, coordinate-systems, fixed-point-theorems

I have a problem that I am trying to solve and I don't know how to approach it.

I am trying to position myself in 2d space using Bluetooth Beacons.

Basically i have my 2 beacons:

- BEACON 1 at coordinates (50, 638)
- BEACON 2 at coordinates (586, 10)

I can calculate the distance to these beacons and for example I get:

- Distance to BEACON 1 = 188 cm
- Distance to BEACON 2 = 646 cm

And I need to find the coordinates of where I am.

It would have been easier to do if I had 3 beacons, but I think it may be possible with 2 as well. As I thought about it there can be 2 positions where I could possibly be, so that the distances that I found to be correct.

We can see here in this drawing that I made:

[image]

I'm sure there should be some kind of formula in order to find these 2 possible coordinates. I have though about how should I calculate them but I didn't come up with anything. Can someone help me with finding this coordinates?

Comment: What are the equations you would get if you were standing at point $(x,y)$?

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: Look at the method to find the intersection of two circles.

Comment: For example, The distance from $(x,y)$ to beacon 1 would be $\sqrt{(x-50)^2+(y-638)^2}=188$. Do that for the other beacon and you have two equations in two variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

$$\begin{align}
x&=\frac{l}{d}(x_2-x_1) \pm \frac{h}{d}(y_2-y_1) + x_1,\\
y&=\frac{l}{d}(y_2-y_1) \mp \frac{h}{d}(x_2-x_1) + y_1.\\
\end{align}$$

Where:

$$\begin{align}
d&=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}\\
l&=\frac{r_1^2-r_2^2+d^2}{2d}\\
h&=\sqrt{r_1^2-l^2}
\end{align}$$
$r_1=$ distance to BEACON 1,$r_2=$ distance to BEACON 2

This will give you the 2 possible coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$ $(x_2,y_2)$ where you may be standing.